# How to visualize a Bayesian network model constructed with pomegranate

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygraphviz

I want to visualize a Bayesian network created with pomegranate with the following code.

```
import math
from pomegranate import *
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

SOmeone has an idea of how I can to this using matplotlib or pygraphvis?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,0,1,0], 'B':[0,0,1,0,0], 'C':[1,1,0,0,1], 'D':[0,1,0,1,1]})
print(df)
df.head()

model = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(df.to_numpy(), state_names=df.columns.values, algorithm='exact')

print(model)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know for Pomegranate, but if I may, using pyAgrum,

```py
import pyAgrum as gum
import pandas as pd
import pyAgrum.lib.notebook as gnb 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,0,1,0], 'B':[0,0,1,0,0], 'C':[1,1,0,0,1], 'D':[0,1,0,1,1]})
gum.BNLearner(df).useAprioriSmoothing(1e-5).useScoreLog2Likelihood().learnBN()
```

which returns in a jupyter notebook :

[image]

For more information on the learned BN,

```py
bn=gum.BNLearner(df).useAprioriSmoothing(1e-).useScoreLog2Likelihood().learnBN()
gnb.sideBySide(bn,gnb.getInference(bn))
gnb.sideBySide(*[bn.cpt(i) for i in bn.nodes()])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you know how I do this plot in PyCharm IDE?

Comment: pyCharm can edit and visualize notebooks. You can also export those graphs in pdf or png. Please have a look to http://webia.lip6.fr/~phw/aGrUM/docs/last/notebooks/colouringAndExportingBNs.ipynb.html (from cell 7)